# Fit form horizontally in responsive box

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I want the input to adjust so the button doesn't drop to the next line in [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/33cL1v6s/2/).

I've tried a few things but I can't do it in a clean way.

```
<div class="col-lg-3">
<form class="search" method="get" action="/" role="search">
    <input type="search" name="s" placeholder="Search">
    <button class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" role="button" type="submit"></button>
</form>
</div>

form {
    input {
     width: 145px;   
    }
    button {
     width: 50px;   
    }
}
```

Comment: Input and button appear in one line here - are you talking about a specific case (small screens)?

Comment: Yes, somewhere between 768px and 1024px the search button drops to the next line. I've tried adding an @media to set a smaller width on the input for these resolutions but it looks awful.

Comment: Just to get things clearer: you need the button to stay the same size, regardless of screen width, and you want the search box to shrink when needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about you use flexbox if you can suport it?

```
   form { 
        display: flex;
    } 
        input {
         flex-grow: 1;
         width: 100%;
         max-width: 150px;   
        }
        button {
         width: 50px;   
        }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/33cL1v6s/3/

Answer (score 1):

Please updated the following style.

```
button {
     width: 50px;
     left: -5px;
    }
```

Or

Add the display property for the search class.

```
.search {display: inline-flex;}
```

Comment: Sorry, the input box is not changing size

Comment: Please add a relative width with class.